# Python: search for a STR1 in a line and replace the whole line with STR2

Tags: python, string, file, replace, io

I have a file in which I need to search for `STR1` and replace the whole line containing `STR2`. For example the `file1` contains the following data

```
Name: John
Height: 6.0
Weight: 190
Eyes: Blue
```

I need to search for `Name` in the above file and then replace the whole line with `Name: Robert`. I can accomplish this easily in sed as

```
sed -i 's/.*Name.*/Name:Robert/' file1
```

But how to get the same in python. For example I can replace one string with another string using `fileinput` as follows

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("file1", inplace=True):
    # inside this loop the STDOUT will be redirected to the file
    # the comma after each print statement is needed to avoid double line breaks
    print line.replace("Name: John", "Name: Robert"),
```

How to modify the above code to replace the whole line, using `'*'` replaces all the lines in the file even with a search condition (`if "Name" in line`)

Comment: How does the above code not do what you want and what does *using `'*'` replaces all the lines in the file* mean exactly?

Comment: `import re; line = re.sub('.*Name.*/', 'Name:Robert', line)`?

Comment: I want to use the string `Name` instead of `Name: John` as search and replace the whole line, since I dont know the value `John` apriori. The `*` replaces the whole file with the string  `Name: Robert`

Comment: Downvoters should have the decency to tell whats wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.find()` to determine if a string is within another string. [Related Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find).

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input("file1", inplace=True):
    if line.find("Name:") >= 0:
        print "Name: Robert"
    else:
        print line[:-1]
```

Comment: OP already knows about `if "Name" in line`, and he's still having problems, so I doubt `find` will be any better.

Comment: The line[:-1] did the trick. But why `:`? I thought the last entry can simply be accessed with `[-1]`

Comment: Using just `[-1]` will access the last character, adding the colon turned it into a splice, so now it's grabbing everything from the zeroth index to the last index minus one.

Comment: This is excellent and it took forever to find. Also, the question is legit. The haters on python questions are unreal. Not a good community.

Answer (score 1):

Should do exactly what you want.

```
def replace_basic(key_to_replace, new_value, file):
    f = open(file, 'rb').readlines()
    with open(file, 'wb') as out:
        for line in f:
            if key_to_replace in line:
                out.write(new_value+'/n') #asuming that your format never changes then uncomment the next line and comment out this one.
                #out.write('{}: {}'.format(key_to_replace, new_value))
                continue
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: I think you meant `out.write(new_value+'\n')`. That works as suggested. Is there a way to backup the original file in this approach?