# How to search a string(say str1) and replace it with another string(say str2) in a file using python?

Tags: python

I have to search a string(say str1) in a file and replace it with another string(say str2) in that same file. The searching(of str1) and writing(of str2) of the 2 strings will be done on the same file. Please someone suggest some methods or logic for this.

Comment: i'm kind of sure this is duplicated... not sure how to prove it now...
btw what did you try?

Comment: Did you Google "search and replace string in file python" before asking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replacing text in a file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089234/replacing-text-in-a-file-with-python)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Python: search for a STR1 in a line and replace the whole line with STR2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313182/python-search-for-a-str1-in-a-line-and-replace-the-whole-line-with-str2)

Comment: Your question is rather broad in its current state. It would be good if you posted some code that you've written, and ask a specific question about it. But I will mention that the usual practice is to _not_ modify the original file, but to make a new file, and delete the old one (if necessary) once the new file is saved. Otherwise, you risk losing your data if something bad happens, eg loss of power.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do that task:

```
FILE = r'A:\some\sort\of\floppy\file.txt' # The target file.
str1 = '\n'
str2 = '\r\n'

data = ''

with open(FILE) as f: # Comment the "with" block under Python 2.6
    data = f.read()
# Uncomment lines below if the "with" statement is commented
##f = open(FILE)
##data = f.read()
##f.close()
data = data.replace(str1, str2)

with open(FILE, 'w') as f: # Same as for previous "with"
    f.write(data)
# And here too
##f = open(FILE)
##f.write(data)
##f.close()
```